# Is legacy checkpoint endpoint blocking puppy 528 wireless Internet connection and how can I remove it?

Tags: wifi, routing, puppy-linux, protocols, uninstall

Background: Whilst booting with an old flash drive (`SafeXs` by block master) plugged in to my laptop (`DELL` latitude 6430u) I came up against a blue login screen . At full encryption point ... checkpoint endpoint security screen appears that requires a username and password to continue. These I do not have and are no longer supported or held on file.

As locked out of normal desktop environment of laptop, I can't run the appropriate removal software.

I tried to create a live boot usb stick wiih `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.7`, working `Windows 7` `Fat32` Formatted Flash Drive. The `PC` has a `BIOS` that can boot from `USB` set at top of boot order.

Linux ISO `lucid puppy 5.2.8` on USB.

The computer has wireless `EMEA` INTEL Centrino advanced and wireless `EMEA` `dell` wireless 380 Bluetooth driver tho spec refers to `mSATA` SSD card, WLAN card and WWAN. Software driver latitude `E6430U DIAGN` chip type `Intel PCH2`

```
PCI DEVICE ID 1502 PCI bus: device:function 0:25:U
Mac address B8:CA:3A:C6:92:ED
Adapter PBA EO 11FF- OFF
UEFI Driver: Intel (R) PRO/1000
The local wireless is SSID BTHub5-ZPHP, interface type 802.11a/n/ac (upto 1300mb/s on 5ghz or 802.11 b/1/n upto 150 at 2.4ghz. The local network shows a PC connected on 78:e4:00:cb:Id:55 No Ethernet or usb detected.
```

My iPhone appears but my `iPad` does not even though is connected. Am assuming PC connected is my laptop even though puppy is telling me no connection.

Some of the issues encountered. When attempting to tailor puppy environment: Unable to mount sda2 No network interfaces detected Many scripts are terminated including when set up PPPOE No .INF file to try and apply a Ndiswrapper. PPPoE: Client installed. No eth0 or variant listed but default used was eth0 for initial config Demand value 0 continuous IP entered Password entered and matched Connection made 2 interfaces visible First is Lo link encap: local Loopback Rx and Tx bytes match Second is `pppO` Link `encap`: Point to point protocol

```
Inet address: 10.112.112.112 P-t-P: 10.112.112.113
Mask: 255.255.255.255
UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST MTU: 1492 Metric:1
RX bytes 0 TX bytes (118.0 B)
Routing:
10.112.112.113
 genmask 255.255.255.255 ppp0
127.0.0.0 genmask 255.0.0.0 Lo
0.0.0.0  genmask 0.0.0.0 ppp0
```

No wireless extensions detected

Net stats: Active internet (servers and established ) Proto tcp Recv-Q 0 Send-Q 0 Local address 127.0.0.1:631 foreign 0.0.0.0:* listen

Start shell gets timed out whatever value entered 0,1,2

Commands are often terminated or denied.

Overall: Essentially I think that the legacy safestick has led to either the activation of 'traces' of removed software or software has been loaded ,along with drivers, for safestick. The software is no longer used and the company who unilaterally deployed it no longer exist.

How do I get my access back, remove the endpoint security files or sidestep/switch off this login screen ? Given we don't ise
How do I get puppy to work properly on the specified dell model ? Should I download latest puppy onto usb with a partic usb installer and a modem on the usb or in puppy
Help am at breaking point!!